# SQL query repeating results

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table which stores the download ID, post ID, File name, and a timestamp

What i do is loop though all the rows in the table then i loop through again to get the dates matching between 00:00:00 and 23:59:59

This works fine and returns all the results and my download counts. 
The issues is it duplicates many time as theres more than one of the same download on the same day.

I cannot use array_unique or a multidimensional array_unique function because they are timestamped and are always appearing as unique.

```
function download_stats_page_c(){
global $wpdb;
$downloads = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT custom_resource_download_log.* FROM custom_resource_download_log"); ?>

<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/library/datatables/media/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<table id="downloads" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Post</th>
            <th>File</th>
            <th># of Downloads</th>
            <th>Date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
 <?php
foreach ($downloads as $download) {
    $pid = $download->post_id; $file_id = $download->file_id; $time = $download->timestamp;
    $time_str = substr($time, 0, strrpos($time, ' '));
    $date_from = $time_str." 00:00:00";
    $date_to = $time_str." 23:59:59";
    $Q = "SELECT * FROM `custom_resource_download_log` WHERE `timestamp` BETWEEN '$date_from' AND '$date_to' AND `post_id` = '$pid'";
    $results = $wpdb->get_results($Q);
    foreach($results as $result) {
   ?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <?php echo get_the_title($result->post_id); ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $result->file_name; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM custom_resource_download_log WHERE post_id='$pid' AND file_id='$file_id' AND `timestamp` BETWEEN '$date_from' AND '$date_to'"); ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $time_str; ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
  <?php
    }
}
echo "</tbody></table>";

}
```

Comment: why are you fetching from the same table twice? you get all the records in the first query, so what's the point of refetching the exact SAME data in the inner query?

Comment: I think you can use `Group By file_id` and select the quantity in one query, in that way you can avoid the inner query for the second loop and show only one row per file

Comment: Could anyone be willing to help with writing that query? I just started using SQL queries and as you can see my methods are a little rough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply try this query:

```
SELECT download_id, post_id, file_name, DATE(timestamp) as the_date, COUNT(*) as number_of_downloads 
FROM custom_resource_download_log
GROUP BY download_id, post_id, file_name, the_date ORDER BY the_date
```